# three.js over cdn using svelte or react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, svelte

Is there any way of building my svelte or react application in a way, that the three.js module (which I usually import using npm) will be declared as a script tag which will call the module from a CDN? I would like to keep the advantages of a framework but also be able to reduce my final bundle size, since most of my bundle contains three code.

Thank you for your wisdom

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about your goal of reducing bundle size:

1. Importing from a CDN (your suggestion)
2. Code-splitting

## Importing from a CDN

To keep semantics of ESModules, you may simply replace your current `three.js` imports with a URL from an npm CDN, like `unpkg`:

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| No extra configuration needed | Slower to load, as browser needs to spin up new connections to access third-party CDN |

**Asynchronously**

```html
<script>
  // App.svelte

  import('https://unpkg.com/three@0.133.1/build/three.min.js').then(({ default: THREE }) => {
    // your code here
  });
</script>
```

**Synchronously**

> Note: Importing like this blocks the rest of your script from loading while `three.js` is downloading, which defeats the purpose of the whole shebang. It's just here for completeness

```html
<script>
  // App.svelte

  import { default as THREE } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.133.1/build/three.min.js';

  // your code here
</script>
```

## Code-splitting

This method takes advantage of the fact that you're already using a bundler (probably `rollup`, `vite`, or `webpack`). This answer will focus on `rollup` as it's the default used in `svelte`'s examples.

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Faster to load, as browser can use existing connections to access first-party resources | More complicated to get set up |

**Asynchronously**

In your `rollup.config.js` file, ensure `output.format` is set to `'esm'` & `output.dir` is set instead of `output.file`

```js
// rollup.config.js

import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    sourcemap: !production,
    format: 'esm',
    name: 'app',
    dir: 'public',
  },
  plugins: {
    // your plugins

    svelte({
      compilerOptions: {
        dev: !production,
      },
    }),

    postcss({
      extract: 'bundle.css',
    }),

    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ['svelte'],
    }),

    commonjs(),
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
  // App.svelte

  import('three').then(({ default: THREE }) => {
    // your code here
  });
</script>
```

> Note: There is no synchronous way due to how code-splitting is evaluated at compile time. Plus it doesn't make much sense to do it like that anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the following:

In your "index.html" file, you can import the js file from a CDN as follow:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
```

Then, in the file where you want to use it, which could be a React component for instance, you can do the following:

```
const THREE = window.THREE;
```

Which would replace your import statement, which would have been `import * as THREE from "three";` or `import THREE from "three";`